# Angular Viewchild InfoWindow behaves differently

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

In my angular google map (not agm) project, the map page html file contains a info window component like this.

```
<map-info-window #myInfoWindow>
  <!-- something here -->
</map-info-window>
```

In ts file, I use @ViewChild to grab the info window. When marker is clicked, it calls the function openInfo(). Then this.myMapInfoWindow is opened.

```
@ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) myMapInfoWindow: MapInfoWindow;

openInfo(mk: MapMarker) {
   this.myMapInfoWindow.open(mk);
}
```

So far everything is good. Now, if I change the @ViewChild in the following way

```
@ViewChild('myInfoWindow') myMapInfoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
```

with or without { static: false }, then marker is clicked, in openInfo function, the statement

```
this.myMapInfoWindow.open(mk);
```

is failed with an error

```
TypeError: this.myMapInfoWindow.open is not a function
```

and info window is not opened.

Where am I wrong in @ViewChild with selector or why open is not a function now?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

According to Angular's Changelog one core change is:

"In Angular version 8, it's required that all @ViewChild and @ContentChild queries have a 'static' flag specifying whether the query is 'static' or 'dynamic'."

If you're working on latest version of angular. This might be the reason your code isn't working without the flag.
You can read more about this here:

1. https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration
2. https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-viewchild-static-property-in-ng8/

Comment: thank you for your help. however, I have specifically explained in my post that "with or without { static: false }", I also tried static: true and it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, If you could provide a Stackblitz itwould be great. Also, is there anything in this.myMapInfoWindow when you call `this.myMapInfoWindow.open(mk);` ?